# Why can my second window not access ipcRenderer in Electron

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron, ipc

I'm creating a Electron React TypeScript app and came across a problem with electron `contextBridge`

I have two windows, each with their own page. In the `OverviewPage` (and the main window),I don't have problems to access functions that are exposed via `contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld` in the `preload` file.
However, if I try to access the same api-calls on the `SelfReport` page, I get following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'closePopup')

**My preload.ts**

```ts
const { ipcRenderer, contextBridge } = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api", {
 
  closePopup: (args: any) => ipcRenderer.send("close-popup", args)
  // other calls
});
export {};
```

**In Main.ts Main Window**

```ts
function createWindow(width: any, height: any) {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: width,
    height: height,
    fullscreen: true,
    webPreferences: {
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "/preload.js"),
    },
  });
  if (app.isPackaged) {
    mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "../index.html"));
  } else {
    mainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:3000");
  }
```

**In Main.ts Second Window**

```ts
let popupWindow;
function createPopupWindow(width: any, height: any) {
  popupWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    frame: false,
    resizable: false,
    movable: false,
    focusable: false,
    alwaysOnTop: true,
    skipTaskbar: true,
    height: 300,
    width: 400,
    x: width - 400,
    y: height - 300,

    webPreferences: {
      webPreferences: {
        contextIsolation: true,
        //preload: path.join(__dirname, "/preload.js"),    Do I need this?
      },
    },
  });
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(null);
  popupWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:3000/report"); 
}
```

**In React**

```ts
window.api.closePopup({ close: true });
```

and

```ts
class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {}

    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route element={<WithNavbar />}>
                        <Route path="/" element={<OverviewPage />} />          
                    </Route>
                    <Route element={<WithoutNavbar />}>
                        <Route path="/report" element={<SelfReport />} />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

**In react-app-env.d.ts**

```ts
/// <reference types="react-scripts" />

declare global {
    interface Window {
        api: any;
    }
}
export {};
```

**Note**

- When starting my application, I'm using the built `preload.js` version.
- All React Pages are `Function Components`

Answer (score 0):

Your `Main.ts` (second window) has an extra level of `webPreferences`. That extra level can be removed.

Also, you should un-comment your `preload:` line for your `window.api.closePopup` call to work.

---

`Main.ts` (second window)

```js
let popupWindow;

function createPopupWindow(width: any, height: any) {
    popupWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        frame: false,
        resizable: false,
        movable: false,
        focusable: false,
        alwaysOnTop: true,
        skipTaskbar: true,
        height: 300,
        width: 400,
        x: width - 400,
        y: height - 300,
        webPreferences: {
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, "/preload.js") // Do I need this? Yes
        }
    });

    Menu.setApplicationMenu(null);
    popupWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:3000/report"); 
}
```

Comment: While the extra level was definitely a dumb mistake of mine and thank you for pointing it out, unfortunately that didn't solve the problem. Still getting the same error when trying to make an ipcRenderer Call in my second window. (I uncomment the preload part again as well)

Comment: @Scorpia Let's confirm the `preload.ts` script is loading. Try adding a `console.log('hi');` line to your `preload.ts` script. Do you see an output from your console (in your render process) when the second page loads?

Comment: nvm, for some reason it works now - Only thing I did was to change `loadUrl` of main window to `mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "../index.html"));` Thanks nevertheless

Comment: can you share the solution, face a similar problem trying to send something from window to other window